# Some DOI links are not properly clickable

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

Some [digital object identifier (DOI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier) links are not  properly clickable.

Example: http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/(sici)1099-1573(200003)14:2<118::aid-ptr493>3.3.co;2-g

Comment: That'll be the special characters. You can fix it by using the `[]()` markdown link syntax instead of the raw URL.